# Stainless tip for thermistor

Tags: extruder, hotend, thermistor

I would like to secure my hotend thermistor in a more reliable way (now it is just thermistor plugged in the hotend :D). I want to have a stainless steel tip for it to fix it inside hotend with a screw (The same approach as used for the heating cartridge). I have thermistors, but I cannot find any tips to buy separately.

Maybe you have some links for this kind of stainless-steel tips? Or some keywords I can use to search them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that the hot block has to match the temp sensor. There are a couple available commercial options for hotblocks with cartridge-and-setscrew temp sensors, but they're not thermistors:

- E3D PT100 RTD -- requires a special amp (http://e3d-online.com/V6-PT100-Sensor-Kit)

[image]

- Carl Raffle Tecto Heater Block with thermocouple -- works as-is in Mightyboard-based printers, but requires a thermocouple amp for boards that use thermistors (http://shop.raffle.ch/shop/tecto-heater-block/)

[image]

Other popular options for thermocouples include a brass thermowell crimped onto the tip of the TC (Makerbot and FlashForge) or an eyelet lug crimped onto the tip of the TC (Wanhao).

The best off-the-shelf solution for most printers is probably to use an E3Dv6 hot block, which uses a screw and washer to clamp the thermistor leads so the glass bead tip can't pull free of its pocket.

Comment: Thanks man, "brass thermowell" is exactly what I was looking for. I just didn't know how to call it (maybe because I'm not native English speaker). Other things are really interesting too, thanks for your help. That is the link to thermowells I found: http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/thermometer-with-brass-thermowell_1780646847.html?spm=a2700.7724838.0.0.vhGi41

Comment: Or this link: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/3-30mm-Stainless-Stell-one-End-Closed-thermocouple-Pt100-protection-Tube-thermowell/32307713415.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.119.bjO0ZF&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_1,searchweb201644_2_505_506_503_504_10020_502_10001_10002_10017_10005_10006_10021_10003_10004_10022_10018_10019,searchweb201560_1,searchweb1451318400_-1,searchweb1451318411_-1&btsid=6d095233-1baf-4d07-95da-c21fd0d660a9

Answer (score 3):

I am not too sure what you're searching for, but I imagine it to be a kind of thermistor housing to distribute pressure from the screw while maintaining good heat conductance.

I first have to say that I'd be afraid to damage the glass droplet of the typical thermistor design by putting pressure to them, especially including later thermal expansion. However, I never tried and we might find some valuable experience on that in other answers here.

If what I assumed in the first paragraph is true, I would suggest forming some housing yourself with copper foil or copper sheets, since the heat conductance of copper is good and it is more or less soft.
However, as a more simple solution, you might just cut the metal part of a 'wire ferrule', if you got some lying around. (Wikipedia has no english article for this, so I link the german one for the images: [Aderendhülse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aderendh%C3%BClse))

Additional info: Can't you clamp the thermistor the way it is done in the E3D V6 hotend, see [this image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/3DModularSystems/Scalar/master/Documentation/Photos/Head/E3D%20V6/Head%20-%20012%20-%20ThermistorBent.jpg)?

[image: Thermistor in E3D V6 hotend]

Thermal contact should be quite good and you don't have any problems which could lead to damage of the thermistor.

Comment: You understand me 100% right.The think is that it is much chipper for me to buy these enclosures than to spend my time for it. I was sure that such a think exists, but I did't know how to call it. That is exactly what I was looking for:http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/shanghai-brass-thermowell_60362628006.html?spm=a2700.7724857.29.339.kY5eXu

Comment: The idea with screw and washer doesn't sounds nice for me because hole is twice as much bigger then thermistor, so I was not sure about thermal conductivity, which can change because of position of sensor.

Answer (score 3):

My thermistors came with a small spring surrounding them, which seems to work pretty well for this (see also [E3D Thermistor Alternative](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/293)). It's pretty close to the size of the spring in an ordinary pen, so you could just try one of those, or you could wind one from copper wire. I always use thermal grease as well, just like you'd use for heat sinks.

[image](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1377/6475/products/Thermistor_Wired_Black_grande.jpg) from [B3 Innovations - Thermistors (Gen1)](https://www.b3innovations.com/products/thermistors-gen1)

[image: Thermistors (Gen1)]

Comment: Can you take a picture please? I don't really understand how it can work :/

Comment: Here's a link to the picture from B3 Innovations, where I bought mine: https://www.b3innovations.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Pico-Hot-end-e1417577727405.jpg This shows it installed on a hotend, but they sell the "thermistor assembly" by itself, or as mentioned you could do something similar.

Comment: Aha, looks really nice. It can prevent wire from banding, good idea. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Your link to the image has expired, it would have been a good idea to include the actual photo in your answer (in case of the inevitable link rot). I have had a search, is this what the photo was of? If so, would you like to edit and add it to your answer? [image](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1377/6475/products/Thermistor_Wired_Black_grande.jpg) from [Thermistors (Gen1)](https://www.b3innovations.com/products/thermistors-gen1)